# Core18: Configure /etc/issue and /etc/motd in custom image

Tags: configuration, snap, ubuntu-core, etc

I'd like to give users instructions to log into a web interface via `/etc/issue` when installing my image, however, the root directory is read only in Ubuntu Core. Is there a clever way this can be done before running `ubuntu-image`?

Alternatively, for `motd`, there's [pam_motd](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/pam-motd) which allows the usage of shell scripts on login to display `motd` messages. Is there something like that for `issue`?

Comment: What build time?

Comment: During the compilation of the image. I think that's the only time that it's possible, since the image mounts root as read-only. @user535733

Comment: Okay, now I'm confused. You don't compile Ubuntu Core. You make your customizations in the rewritable partition (like getting rid of your ssh login, adding the webserver, selecting a custom UUID, etc). Then you install the custom system into your device using three partitions: Core A, Core B, and your customizations. Ubuntu Core will regularly update with security patches and bugfixes, but they won't break your customizations...if done properly.

Comment: Apologies, I'm not that familiar with snaps or Snappy. By compilation, or build time, I mean the span of time between when you strike the enter key on your `ubuntu-image` command and flashing the image to your device. I would like a way to modify my `/etc/issue` message (the message that displays to the user when asking for login) before or during that process.

Comment: Okay, I think that makes sense. So, how would I go about doing that? Can you post an answer?

Comment: For /etc/issue, I was flat wrong - attempts to use writable partition failed.. Sorry to lead you to a dead end. Consider asking the Ubuntu Core developers at snapcraft.io